# Bitwise right shift operator in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In Java, -4 >> 2 gives -1 but -5 >> 2 gives -2. Can anybody explain why? 
Here is a sample code:

```
byte r=-5;
r>>=2;
System.out.println(r);
```

Also in this scenario >> and >>> operators give the same answer. Can anyone explain that as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take a look at the bits.  Using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation, the bits for `-4` and `-5` are, showing only the last 8 bits for brevity:

```
-4: 1111 1100      
-5: 1111 1011
```

Bit shifting to the right 2 positions, with sign extension:

```
-4 >> 2: 1111 1111 (-1)
-5 >> 2: 1111 1110 (-2)
```

Normally, you think of `>>>` not using sign extension, and this is true, but in this case:

```
r >>>= 2;
```

... the value `r` is promoted to `int` for the bit-shift operation using binary numeric promotion, but the compound assignment operator casts the returned value back to `byte`, and the shifted-in zero "disappears".

```
byte r = -5;     // 1111 1100
r >>>= -2;       // promoted to int:   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010
                 // bit shift:         00111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
                 // cast back to byte: 11111110 (-2)
```

The [JLS, Section 15.26.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), talks about the casting operation done in compound assignment operators:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

That is, in this case, the result of the bit-shift is casted back to `byte`.

The same cast-back-to-byte operation occurs when the value of `r` is `-4`.

Note that if the assignment part wasn't done, then you wouldn't see the same answer, because it wouldn't cast the result back to `byte`:

```
System.out.println(r >>> 2);
```

Then you would see:

```
1073741822
```

Comment: >>>= gives the same answer. I am sure about that.

Comment: I have added explanation why you still see the same answer.

Comment: when we directly print r >>> 2 , it prints the answer as an integer, right?

Comment: Correct, binary numeric promotion occurs, so the result of `r >>> 2` is an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody explain why (-4 >> 2 is -1, and -5 >> 2 is -2)?

Binary -4 byte looks like this: `11111100`. When you shift it right while extending the sign, you get `11111111` (the ones on the left is *sign extension*, i.e. keeping the sign bit while shifting left). This is `-1` in two's complement representation.

Binary -5 byte looks like this: `11111011`. When you shift it right while extending the sign, you get `11111110` (again, the ones on the left is sign extension). This is -2.

> `>>` and `>>>` operators give the same answer. Can anyone explain that as well?

Shifting is performed in integers. When you use `>>>` to shift `-4` *without* sign extension, you get `00111111111111111111111111111111`. When you convert it to `byte`, you chop off the top 24 bits, ending up with the lower eight bits all set to `1`. Same goes for `>>>` of `-5`.

Comment: thank you @dasblinkenlight, that clears my second doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of negative numbers, in memory they are stored using a technique called two's complement. In this example, 5 is: 0...0101 (i am removing a lot of 0's for sake of length
so when you shift 0101 twice you get:

```
0101 >> 0010
0010 >> 0001
```

0001 is 1

in two's complement you have 1...1011 (inverse all the bits then add a binary 1)
so when you shift 1011 you have

```
1011 >> 1101 (we carry the other 1's)
1101 >> 1110 (we carry the other 1's)
```

1...1110 is the negative for -2

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the two's complement format to represent negative numbers.

-5 is represented as `11111011` in binary which when right-bitshifted 2 bits over becomes `11111110`, which is -2.  Similarly, -4 is represented as `11111100`, which when right-bitshifted by 2 becomes `11111111`, which is -1 in decimal.

The reason `>>` and `>>>` appear to be the same is because the `>>>` operator is a logical right shift on integers, not bytes.  Therefore java is type casting r to an int before it preforms the logical shift and then truncating the bitstring to only the least significant 8 bits.  Because the integer representation of -5 is `11111111111111111111111111111011` and the logical shift 2 right is `11111111111111111111111111111110` which is typecast to a byte of `11111110`, which is -2.

If you try the following code you see the results:

```
byte r = -5;
System.out.println(r >> 2);
System.out.println(r >>> 2);
r>>>=2;
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

The byte -4 [== 0xFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). If you shift that arithmetically right (i.e. preserving the sign bit) by 2 bits you get 0xFF, which is -1.

-5 == 0xFB. If you shift that arithmetically right by 2 bits you get 0xFE, which is -2.